# Is there a way to set EOL to LF in Visual Studio for whole solution or project?

Tags: c, visual-studio, eol

In Visual Studio you can set file's EOL to CRLF, LF,  or CR, however you can do it only to a single file. I'm looking for a way that will make sure that every new file made in my solution will automatically use LF. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good move! A simple way to get this behavior is to move from this legacy system to linux or OS/X :)

Comment: Open the file for output in binary mode. Or do you mean the source code editor?

Comment: @chqrlie, I use a modern system and it doesn't have a problem with EOL. Use of LF is a design choice.

Comment: @Wispy: my comment was a humorous tease. The CRLF convention, copied from CP/M for MS/DOS in 1981 was already obsolescent then. Apple gave up on the CR convention in 2001. [Errare humanum est, perseverare diabolicum](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errare_humanum_est,_perseverare_diabolicum)

Comment: @chqrlie, I've done just that actually (moved from the legacy system)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding an `.editorconfig` file in the root directory of the project (or solution) with the following entry should set line endings to `LF` by default (for newly added lines, see the notes below).

```
    [*]
    end_of_line = lf
```

Quoting from the [Create portable, custom editor settings with EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019) page.

> You can add an [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) file to your project or codebase to enforce consistent coding styles for everyone that works in the codebase.
>
> The editor in Visual Studio supports the core set of [EditorConfig properties](https://editorconfig.org/#supported-properties): 
> [...]   `end_of_line`
>
> When you add an .editorconfig file to a folder in your file hierarchy, its settings apply to all applicable files at that level and below.
>
> When you add an EditorConfig file to your project in Visual Studio, new lines of code are formatted according to the EditorConfig settings. The formatting of existing code is not changed unless you run one of the following commands:
>
> - Code Cleanup (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+E), which applies any white space settings, such as indent style, and selected code style settings, such as how to sort using directives.
> - Edit > Advanced > Format Document (or Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D in the default profile), which only applies white space settings, such as indent style.
>   Note

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this looks like exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note- working on a Unity project... I found my .editorconfig in the Assets folder

Comment: @KevinVictor Thanks. I am not familiar with Unity projects, but going by the documentation that would mean the settings in the `.editorconfig` you found apply to files under the `Assets` folder, only. Text files elsewhere in the project would still use the defaults. Adding an `.editorconfig` file in the root directory of the project would apply to all files under it, both under `Assets` and elsewhere.